# Logarithmic integration of two related terms

Tags: integration

How do I prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} du \left(\frac{u^{2}}{(u+a)^{3}} - \frac{u^{2}}{(u+b)^{3}}\right) = \ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)?$$

Comment: There is a general [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), however in this case you can just simply find the antiderivative and take the limits. It's not that hard

Comment: What is the antiderivative in this case?

Comment: if you want to be fancy, integrate $(z^2(z+b)^3-z^2(z+b)^3)\frac{\log(z)}{(z+b)^3(z+b)^3}$ over a keyhole contour in the complex plane. Otherwise follow @Jack D'Aurizo's advice

Comment: $$\frac{u^2}{(u+a)^3}=\frac{u-a}{(u+a)^2}+\frac{a^2}{(u+a)^3}=\frac{1}{u+a}-\frac{2a}{(u+a)^2}+\frac{a^2}{(u+a)^3}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the substitution $t = u + c$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{(u+c)^3}\,du = \int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2-2tc+c^2}{t^3}\,dt = \int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt - \int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{2c}{t^2}\,dt + \int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{c^2}{t^3}\,dt = \int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt + 2 - \frac{1}{2}$$

and plug in $a$ and $b$ to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} du \left(\frac{u^{2}}{(u+a)^{3}} - \frac{u^{2}}{(u+b)^{3}}\right) = \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt-\int_{b}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt = \ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: You need to be very careful with this last part: $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt-\int_{b}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt = \ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, of course. It boils down to 
$$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt-\int_{b}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{u+a}-\frac{1}{u+b})\,du$$

Comment: @AnubisBlack: technically speaking, no, it doesn't. In the LHS there is the difference between two diverging integrals, in the RHS there is a converging integral. It is like stating that $\infty-\infty = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By integration by parts it boils down to
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{u+a}-\frac{1}{u+b}\right)\,du = \log(b)-\log(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd u \bracks{{u^{2} \over \pars{u + a}^{3}} -
{u^{2} \over \pars{u + b}^{3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\ \
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{u^{2} \over \pars{u + a}^{3}} - {1 \over u + a}}\dd u -
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{u^{2} \over \pars{u + b}^{3}} - {1 \over u + b}}\dd u
+
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over u + a} - {1 \over u + b}}\dd u =
\\[5mm] = &\ \
\braces{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{u^{2} \over \pars{u + 1}^{3}} - {1 \over u + 1}}\dd u -
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{u^{2} \over \pars{u + 1}^{3}} - {1 \over u + 1}}\dd u}
+
\left.\ln\pars{u + a \over u + b}\right\vert_{\ u\ =\ 0}^{\ u\ \to\ \infty}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{\ln\pars{b \over a}}}
\end{align}